# In version 9 PlotLegends, how can I remove the strange edges that appear around LegendMarkers?

Tags: plotting, graphics, version-9, legending

I'm running Mathematica version 9.  I am using `ListPlot` to plot two sets of data.  For each data set, I am using different `PlotMarkers`: for the first data set, I use red disks, while for the second data set, I use red rectangles.  To do this, I define `Graphics` objects `redDisk` and `redRectangle` as shown below.  (I have found that it is necessary to define nonzero `ImagePadding` to prevent the edges of the `Graphics` from being cut off.)

Next, I want to display a plot legend describing the two different `PlotMarkers`.  To do this, I want to use the `PlotLegends` option that is newly implemented in Mathematica version 9.  I define a `PointLegend` called `legend`.  Within `PointLegend`, I use pass in the objects `redDisk` and `redRectangle` to the `LegendMarkers` option.  Then I give `legend` to the `PlotLegends` option of `ListPlot` and use the `Placed` function to position the legend in the plot.

The code to do all of this is the following:

```
(* Define PlotMarkers *)
pm = 8; (* size of PlotMarkers *)
redDisk = 
  Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> (pm + 2), 
   ImagePadding -> {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}];
redRectangle = 
  Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> (pm + 1), 
   ImagePadding -> {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}];

(* Define a PointLegend using the PlotMarkers defined above *)
legend = PointLegend[{Red, Red}, {"red disk", "red rectangle"}, 
   LabelStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Arial"}, 
   LegendFunction -> "Frame", 
   LegendMarkers -> {redDisk, redRectangle}];

(* Create some data to plot *)
myRange = Range[0, 2 Pi, 0.175];
diskData = Transpose[{myRange, Sin[myRange]}];
rectangleData = Transpose[{myRange, Cos[myRange]}];

(* Plot the data *)
myPlot = ListPlot[
  {diskData, rectangleData}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, BaseStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Arial"}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, PlotMarkers -> {redDisk, redRectangle}, 
  ImageSize -> 500,
  PlotLegends -> Placed[legend, Scaled[{0.65, 0.85}]]
  ]
```

which gives this output:

[image: SmallGraphic]

***However,*** when I zoom in on this graphical output, I see that the markers inside the `PointLegend` do not appear exactly the same as the `PlotMarkers` of `ListPlot`.  ***Specifically,*** the markers inside the `PointLegend` appear to have a strange gray edge or border:

[image: ZoomGraphic]

where I used the Mathematica front end's magnification feature to zoom in on the `myPlot` graphical output.

The strange gray edges/borders persist even when I export `myPlot` to, for example, a pdf file:

```
(* Export the data as a pdf file *)
Export["example.pdf", myPlot]
```

When I open `example.pdf` in a pdf viewer and zoom in, I see the following.  The strange gray edges/borders are still apparent in the `LegendMarkers` within the legend:

[image: PDFGraphic]

**So, my question is, how can I remove the gray edges/borders of the `LegendMarkers` so that the `LegendMarkers` and `PlotMarkers` look the same?**

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of simply using `Red` as the directive, set the face and edge colors explicitly so that there is no ambiguity. If you use `FaceForm@Red` and `EdgeForm@Red` (or `None`) in your definitions for `redDisk` and `redRectangle`, you get legend markers without black borders.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!  This may justify or require a separate question, but is there any way to force the `LegendMarkers` to be the same size as the `PlotMarkers`?  In the plot, it looks like the `redDisk` `PlotMarkers` are somewhat larger than the `redDisk` `LegendMarkers`.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible. Off the top of my head, the solution is to use `{redDisk, size}` in the plot marker and legend marker option. However, the value of `size` is typically a fraction of the size of the parent figure (e.g. 0.04). Since your legend and plot figures are of different sizes, the value you choose for `size` in each must be so that the disks look the same for both plots. I don't have the time right now to work on it and write up an automated solution, but this is probably sufficient info for you to manually tweak them for now. Also, I suppose there might be a question here...

Comment: Thanks.  This helps a lot!  Yes, it seems that there might be a question here, too.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Grayish (actually black with `Opacity[.3]` marker edges are the result of default setting for marker style:

```
Legending`LegendDump`$DefaultMarkerStyle
```

> `EdgeForm[Directive[Opacity[0.3], GrayLevel[0]]]`

You can reset this to `EdgeForm[]`:

```
Legending`LegendDump`$DefaultMarkerStyle = EdgeForm[];

PointLegend[{Red, Red}, {"red disk", "red rectangle"}, 
 LabelStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Arial"}, LegendFunction -> "Frame",
 LegendMarkers -> {redDisk, redRectangle}]  // Magnify[#, 5] &
```

[image]

Comment: This is what actually worked for me, especially when trying to get "unfilled" markers. E.g. `LegendMarkers->Graphics[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Directive[Thickness[0.2], Opacity[1], Blue]], SSSTriangle[1, 1, 1]}]` for a blue triangle that roughly matches the blue triangle from `PlotMarkers->"OpenMarkers"`. If you don't include the `Opacity[1]`, the edge still looks greyish.

Answer (score 3):

You may also supply `EdgeForm[]` in `Graphics[...]` to force Mathematica not to draw edges.

Comment: @bobthechemist The solution works for me in version 10.0.1 under Windows.

Comment: However now that I look again this appears to be a duplicate of rm -rf's answer.  @Leonx are you proposing something else?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I just tried to provide an alternative answer as rm -rf's answer 'EdgeForm@Red (or None)', pardon me I didn't pay attention to the 'None' option.

Comment: @bobthechemist, sorry, I am still new and hit the big red button instead of the grey one.

Comment: I see.  Experienced users know that one can often use `...[]` or `{}` in place of `None` but some may not.  I appreciate your intention so +1 (meaning my positive vote) on this answer.

Comment: @Leonx no problem - welcome aboard.