# How can I save both the plot and the legend together?

Tags: plotting, legending

In this example, how can I put the legend *inside* the graph? Currently, when I save the graph, only the graph is saved, not the legend.

```
Expr1 = -2 p + 1
Expr2 = 2 p - 1
Expr3 = p - 1/2
Plot[{Expr1, Expr2, Expr3}, {p, 0, 1},
 BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4], 
 PlotLegends -> 
  LineLegend["Expressions", BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4]]]
Solve[Expr1 == Expr2, p]
```

Also, how can I insert the solution in the last line, also inside the graph?

Here you can see the result:

[image: Screenshot of graph]

Comment: Strongly related: "[Creating legends for plots with multiple lines?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4028/280)"

Comment: Also related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34357/280

Comment: How to position legends where you want them: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7547/how-to-position-legends-exactly-where-i-want-them

Comment: I think the easier is to save the plot into a variable, i.e., pLot and then export this to an external file. Often I manage to select the legend and the plot at the same time, than I can copy to pdf format or image format.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is how to save the graph, legend and all:

[image: saves]

Another way would be to use `Rasterize`:

```
Rasterize[Plot[...]]
```

The legend and the graph is now one image.

Comment: I like this one, but I don´t know how to select legends and plot. The plot is easy, but I can´t select the 2 thing at same time.

Comment: @MikaIke Why do you need to select them at the same time? If you save it this way, the plot and the legend will be saved together as if you had selected it as one picture. btw. I didn't include how to put the solution in, but I would've done it like b.gatessucks did it.

Comment: @MikaIke you can drag the cursor over both the legend and the plot. Start slightly to the right of the legend, click down, drag over both until both are selected (they are semi-transparently colored), then release mouse button.

Comment: While this method works, it still includes the Out[] part in the image, which I would rather not have. I understand this is a very old post, but instead of making a new one I figured it would be good to ask here first.

Comment: @user129412 It doesn't include Out[], I just tried it to be sure.

Comment: @C.E. For me it does, version 10.2.0.0 on Windows 10 x64. However, I found that I can select the Out[] part and press delete, which will also remove it from the export part. A slight nuisance but not an issue.

Comment: @user129412 Maybe you are doing it differently somehow. I tested this in 10.1, 10.2 and 10.3 on OS X and none of them include Out[]. I also asked in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29189764#29189764) and another user confirmed that it doesn't include Out[] for him on Windows 10. Given this difficulty with reproducing your issue I don't think you can hope to get an answer in this comment thread, you would have to ask a question about it to bring more attention to the issue.

Comment: @C.E. A very valid point. I'll experiment with it a bit more myself. Thanks for trying it in any case!

Comment: For me it includes the `Out[..]=` if I select the cell or bluntly highlight the content. If I try to carefully highlight exactly two items using shift+arrows, I can get it to save without the `Out[..]=`.

Comment: @Džuris That's a good, useful comment. However, I have only observed that behavior when exporting .pdf files, not for example .png files. Can you confirm whether it includes `Out[..] = ` regardless of what file type you use?

Comment: @C.E. I can only test that with PDF. When trying to save as png, I get nothing but a bunch of errors.

Comment: @Džuris Strange, that I have never seen.

Comment: Yes, when trying to save as PNG, I get error like 'The specified setting for the option WindowSize cannot be used.'

Comment: The WidowSize error can be fixed by making sure the zoom setting in your notebook is set to 100%.

Answer (score 11):

You can define :

```
sol = Solve[Expr1 == Expr2, p][[1, 1]] ;
plot = Plot[{Expr1, Expr2, Expr3}, {p, 0, 1}, 
        BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4], 
        PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend["Expressions", BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4]], {Left, Center}], 
        Epilog -> Inset[sol, {0.5, 0.5}]]
```

[image: plot]

and export with

```
Export["/tmp/plot.png", plot]
```

Comment: +2 for code, -1 for the ugliest plot I've seen so far today! :)

Comment: @cormullion You should have seen what I did yesterday at work !

Comment: e.g. 1 `Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotLegends -> Placed[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {Center, Top}]]`
 $$~$$
e.g. 2 `Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {Center, Top}]]`
 $$~$$
Using `placed`.
 $$~$$
`Placed[expr,pos]` represents an expression expr placed at relative position pos in a chart or other display. 
$$~$$
contourplot: Using `Rasterize` $$~$$
`Rasterize[
 Labeled[ContourPlot[1/(1/P + 1/R), {P, 0, 1}, {R, 0, 1}, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic], {"P", "R"}, {Left, Bottom}]]`
$$~$$
Then you can use `Save Image As ...` to save plot.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use the full form position specification with `Placed` to position legend "inside" the graph and use `Legended` to put any additional legends.

```
Legended[Plot[{Expr1, Expr2, Expr3}, {p, 0, 1}, 
  BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4], 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[LineLegend["Expressions", 
     BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4]], {1.05, 0.5}]], 
   Placed[First@First@Solve[Expr1 == Expr2, p], {0.5, 1}]]
```

[image: legended graph]

Comment: Alternatively, `Placed[...,{Right,Right}]` works as well.

Comment: This also works for the Save Graphic As... with PDFs! I recommend the simple solution by @Kai. Just put the usual PlotLegends where the dots are.

Answer (score 2):

I'm late into this, but

```
plot = Plot[..., PlotLegends -> {...}]
Export["file.pdf", plot]
```

works fine for me in v12. ([C.E.'s answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35656/72352) of `Save selection as...` puts an "Out[#]" on the side). So exporting to a PDF file could be a solution if one does not want to rasterize.