# How to export 3 plots in a row in eps extension?

Tags: export, grid-layouts, eps-format

I'm trying to save three plots with a legend at the end using the methodology described in another StackExchange post: [How can I save both the plot and the legend together?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35653/how-can-i-save-both-the-plot-and-the-legend-together)

I'm using Row[] to organize my three plots one next to the other (I want to show how the outcome of a system changes if feed with three different parameters). However, once the eps file is produced, the three plots appear as a column in the file, which is not the way I want to embedded my graph in the Latex file. Is there a way to save the plots as they appear in the Mathematica output, i.e., as a row?

EDIT:

I can't post all my code, but here is an abridged of what I'm doing:

```
pars1 = {n -> 0.3, k -> 2};
pars2 = {n -> 0.2, k -> 4};
pars3 = {n -> 0.1, k -> 5};

sol1 = NDSolve[{My equations} /. pars1, {y, s}, {t, 0, 100}];
sol2 = NDSolve[{My equations} /. pars2, {y, s}, {t, 0, 100}];
sol3 = NDSolve[{My equations} /. pars3, {y, s}, {t, 0, 100}];
Row[{
     Plot[Evaluate[{y[t], s[t]} /. sol1], {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All],
     Plot[Evaluate[{y[t], s[t]} /. sol2], {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All],
     Plot[Evaluate[{y[t], s[t]} /. sol3], {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
     PlotLegends -> {"y", "s"}]
}]
```

This code produces three plots in a row as

```
X X X(with legend)
```

But the result after exporting is a file like this:

```
X
X
X(with legend)
```

Bear in mind that the procedure described in the older post has nothing to do with code. It's just clicking and saving.

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using?

Comment: @mgamer I added the code in an edit

Comment: There is such a thing as `GraphicsRow`, that might work.

Comment: I don't know whether it's a good idea to close "...in eps extension" as a duplicate of "exporting a rasterized..." since eps is a vector format. But maybe it doesn't matter. The `GraphicsRow` solution in that Q&A will not rasterize the image.

Comment: @C. E. If you do want a vector graphics EPS file, Mr. Wizard's solution in the linked question of using `ImageSize -> {10^6.}` as an option in the `Row[~]` will successfully prevent wrapping for EPS files even if the Rasterize command used in Mr. Wizard's example is absent.