# How can I save both the plot3D and the legend together?

Tags: plotting

I want to save both the plot and the legend together,I have used the Export to save the picture.The picture is as shown below.
[image]

But it did not achieve my intended purpose. I want to achieve the kind of the following figure, but this can only be achieved through the amplification, but the enlarged picture can not be saved.
I need  help!
[image]

Comment: You really need to edit this question and include the code that generated the plot and the code that did the exporting. Be sure to include all supporting code so all variables are defined.

Comment: Have you seen [How can I save both the plot and the legend together?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/35653/484)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to export the expression of the plot, for example, as a png to the directory in which you have your notebook. Example:

```
plot = Plot3D[Sin[x^2 + y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "f(x,y)"}]
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "example.png", plot]
```

This will export the expression `plot` to the directory in which the notebook has been saved as "example.png" and you will see the plot with the legend

[image]