# Save a histogram

Tags: graphics

What is the best way (not necessary the easiest way) to save a histogram with labeled axis.  I know there is a "save as" or "copy" in the context menu but in my case the name of the axis (labeled axis) are not selected and so not saved.

Comment: Does [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35656/731) help?

Comment: Hi thanks. I will go through :)