# How to correctly export a plot in pdf?

Tags: plotting, export, pdf-format

I'm currently plotting three functions on a graph using:

```
p0 = p /. 
  Select[Solve[p (p^2 + p - 1/2) - 3/4 == 0, p], 
Element[p /. #1, Reals] &][[1]]

Plot[{(p (((3 p)/8 + 5/8) p - 3/16) - 15/32)/(
  p (p^2 + p - 1/2) - 3/4), (p (1/4 p (p + 2) - 1/8) - 3/8)/(
  p (p^2 + p - 1/2) - 3/4), (p (1/8 p (p + 3) - 1/16) - 9/32)/(
  p (p^2 + p - 1/2) - 3/4)}, {p, 0, 1}, Exclusions -> {p0}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 1}, ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Gray], 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Player 1", "Player 2", "Player 3"}, Below]]
```

Getting the following output:

[image]

So far, I have found four ways to export the plot in pdf format, but none of them is satisfactory. In fact, I have tried the four ways proposed in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35653/how-can-i-save-both-the-plot-and-the-legend-together?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), but without success:

1. If I select the graph and I choose to `save it as...` after right-clicking, **I miss the legend** (I need the legend).
2. If I use `Rasterize[Plot[...]]`, the image **loses A LOT of quality**. Of course, I do not want that.
3. If I use `Export["plot.pdf", plot]`, **nothing happens** (I mean, the plot in pdf appears nowhere). Of course, I need the plot
4. If I right-click and then I select `Save Selection As...`, **I get `Out[x]=` next to my plot**, as the following picture shows. Of course, I do not want that.

[image]

Therefore, my question is: **how can I export the plot and the legend without losing quality and without the ugly `Out[x]=` to the left of my plot?**

Thank you all very much in advanced for your time and effort.

Comment: You have not assigned `plot` a value in the above code so not certain how you expect `Export["plot.pdf", plot]` to work.  In any case, `Export["plot.pdf", plot, "PDF", "AllowRasterization"->False]` will get you what you are seeking (if you assign the plot to the `plot` variable) and it is directly in the options of the [`"PDF"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/PDF.html) documentation.  The documentation is your friend.

Comment: When using `Export` I was caling `plot = Plot[{(p (((3 p)/8 + 5/8) p - 3/16) - 15/32)/(
  p (p^2 + p - 1/2) - 3/4), (p (1/4 p (p + 2) - 1/8) - 3/8)/(
  p (p^2 + p - 1/2) - 3/4), (p (1/8 p (p + 3) - 1/16) - 9/32)/(
  p (p^2 + p - 1/2) - 3/4)}, {p, 0, 1}, Exclusions -> {p0}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 1}, ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Gray], 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Player 1", "Player 2", "Player 3"}, Below]]]`. Why wasn't this enough? Also, by setting `plot=Plot[...]` and then running the line you suggested, I still found no output. Shouldn't the output be in the root folder?

Comment: Because that code as a syntax error so nothing is assigned to `plot`. Notice the red highlighted final bracket and the red highlighted cell marker when that code is evaluated.

Comment: Sorry, the third closing bracket is an addition of mine in the comment, but it's not the code I ran. I still get no pdf output even when I correct this (all the rest is fine and no error is shown). I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Again, read the documentation. What is the current working directory your session? See [`Directory`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Directory.html) and friends. That is where your pdf file has been exported.  The documentation is your friend.

Comment: Would you be so kind to summarise your comments into an answer for me to accept it? If you think it's more convenient, I can also delete the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use the `"AllowRasterization"` option of [`"PDF"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/PDF.html) to prevent rasterization. The exported file will be found in the session's working directory, see [`Directory`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Directory.html).

```
Export["plot.pdf", plot, "PDF", "AllowRasterization"->False]
```

The working directory can be open directly from the notebook with

```
File@Directory[]
```

and then clicking on the double arrow at the end of the directory name.

Hope this helps.