# How to add a border to a plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics

Consider a plot as

```
ListLinePlot[{{10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}}]
```

[image]

I want to add a border to this plot like this

[image]

I tried to use

```
ImageCompose[
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[{RGBColor[192/255, 0, 0], Thickness[0.01]}], 
   LABColor[1, 0, 0, 0], 
   Rectangle[{0, 0}, {x, y}, RoundingRadius -> 0.1]}], 
 ListLinePlot[{{10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}}]]
```

and checked with different values of `x` and `y`. However, I am not getting the desired border.

How can I do this (without losing the resolution)?

Answer (score 7):

```
pic = Framed[
 ListLinePlot[{
   {10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40},
   {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}}],
 FrameMargins -> 20,
 FrameStyle -> {Thick, Red},
 RoundingRadius -> Scaled[.05]]

Export["/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/pic.EPS", pic]

(* "/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/pic.EPS" *)
```

[image]

Comment: How can I now save the plot along with the border?

Comment: What about naming the plot `pic=Framed[...]`?

Comment: @Majis Same as in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35656/731) answer.